# How to log type assertion errors in golang?

Tags: go, error-handling, type-assertion

I have an array of some data which I want to map in `[]string`. I can do it in 2 ways:

a)

```
// someData
s := someData.([]string)
```

In this case, the execution would stop after listing the error on the console.

b)

```
// someData
s, ok := someData.([]string)
```

In this case, no errors would occur but s will have its zero-value

---

I want to log the errors in such type assertion failure cases without stopping the execution. However, when I am using type (b), I cannot see the error details.

The only solution I can think is to use `reflect.TypeOf` and print both the types.

Is there any other way we can get the error when using solution (b)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can construct the log message yourself. There's no need for explicit calls to `reflect` as there's a printf format string `%T` that produces the type.

```
s, ok := someData.([]string)
if !ok {
    log.Printf("got data of type %T but wanted []string", someData)
    ... handle the failure somehow
}
```

Without knowing the context it's hard for me to produce a useful and informational log statement, but you can adapt the idea to suit your use case.

Comment: Surprising that golang doesn't require checking that the type assertion is valid. Couldn't failing to check the validity of the type assertion lead to runtime errors?

Comment: @Kwestion the `ok` value says whether the type assertion is valid.

Comment: Right, and when dealing with imported data such as a config file, or json - its possible that when you assert types you will fail. If your type assertion fails without checking its validity what happens?

Answer (score 4):

Well, depending on how you want to do your type assertions, there is a way of getting the errors both in case a) and b).

So, I will cover b first because if is the most straight forward: you can use the `%T` to get the type of the elements:

```
func typeAssert(i interface{}) []string {
    s, ok := i.([]string)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Printf("interface conversion: interface is %T, not []string\n", i)
    }
    return s
}
```

The other way involves recovering from the error, so you can get the panic message as an error:

```
func assertType(i interface{}) []string {

    // Recover
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    return i.([]string)
}

func main() {
    assertType([]int{42})

    fmt.Println("Recovered from the error")
}
// OUTPUT:
// interface conversion: interface is []int, not []string
// Recovered from the error
```

Of course, you can add your own treatment of the errors, depending of what you want to do. The first solution allows for more flexibility anyway, but `recover`may be handy sometimes (not necessarily in this case).

Here is the link to the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4dMcp2nS6G)